# Easiest way to update an MVC View from a Controller

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am totally new to .NET's MVC framework and have a scarce understanding of how the Model-View-Controller architecture works. I have a simple and basic problem.

In my application, it is a calendar app, I have a Controller named EventsController which overrides a method named `OnCommand`, which is a part of the DayPilot Calendar(open source calendar). Here's my method:

```
protected override void OnCommand( CommandArgs e )
{
    switch (e.Command)
    {
         case "previous":
              StartDate = StartDate.AddMonths(-1);
              StrMonth = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(StartDate.Month);
              Console.WriteLine(StrMonth);
              Query();
              Update(CallBackUpdateType.Full);
              break;
         case "next":
              StartDate = StartDate.AddMonths(1);
              StrMonth = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(StartDate.Month);
              Console.WriteLine(StrMonth);
              Query();
              Update(CallBackUpdateType.Full);                       
              break;                   
        }
}
```

When a forward and backwards arrow are clicked at the top of the calendar - the previous and next are called and **StrMonth** is set to the correct month. There is a div containing the name of the month between the two arrows, it needs to update from the Controller Method or another. How do I update the view from the Controller to correctly change the month displayed at the top of the calendar?

I have tried the following:
-Adding a property to my Event Model named `CurrentMonth` and then using that variable inside of the **div** in the View like this:

`<div>@Model.CurrentMonth</div>`

and then attempting to use an ActionResult in my Controller that updates it for me and calls a Javascript in my View:

**In the Controller:**

```
public ActionResult UpdateMonth(Event model)
{
    model.CurrentMonth = "changeMonth()";
    //return View(model);
}
```

**In the View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     @Model.Item2.CurrentMonth;

     function changeMonth() {
        @ViewBag.strMonth = @Model.Item2.CurrentMonth;
     }

</script>
```

This should be trivial, in almost every other client-server architecture, updating the client is much easier than in MVC. What is the simplest and most basic way to update the View based on a Controller ActionResult or method? Do I need to be using Ajax or the ViewBag/ViewData properties of MVC? An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically you have three options: something is changed on the page without a roundtrip to the server (done by Javascript), a whole page is returned from the server (the method returns a `ActionResult` or any descendant, like `ViewResult`), or just a part of the page is returned (`PartialViewResult`, for example). For this last case, you should use a `Ajax.BeginForm` and its `UpdateTargetId` property specified where the partial view should go. What does the code on the client do when you click on those arrows?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't work with `Event`s the way you may be used to from Web Forms.  By any chance, is this control designed for Web Forms? In that case, you may need to get a new control, because the page lifecycle subsystem it relies on will be completely unavailable to it.

Comment: @Andrew The clicking of the left and right arrows literally just change the month on the DayPilot Calendar(open source) - it uses callback()'s. But Since I am already getting the month to change using those switch cases, I just need to send the variable `StrMonth` from the controller to the view and then update a text element on the page, using **div** or whatever.  And Marc, no this site is set up not for webforms.

Comment: @Chisx, I mean what is the code in the browser behind those arrows. Do they execute a Javascript function? Hit an url? You may have to check the source code of the rendered page.

Comment: They use Javascript yes, sorry misunderstood. Here's the code for just the left arrow: `<a href="javascript:dp.commandCallBack('previous');">` Where dp is a daypilotCalendar object and the commandCallBack actually calls `OnCommand()`, which you can see - is overriden above.

Comment: Can't you find the code for `commandCallBack` in the page's source code?

Comment: Im not really sure what you're suggesting Im already setting a variable and updating it to the correct month when the buttons are hit, now I just need to pass the variable and update the text. There isn't any code written in commandCallBack or OnCommand that actually would change the date on an object- there is no date displayed above the calendar, I am making this happen. In other words, the calendar doesnt display a date so Im having to do this manually

Comment: I downloaded this code. Is it something like this what you are using?
http://mvc.daypilot.org/demo/Calendar/ The `OnCommand` is called when you click on a month's day, but when you click on an arrow, it calls `NavigatorBackend()`, which calls `Dpn().CallBack(this)`. Are you using this same project?

Comment: No actually ours looks like this http://imgur.com/XGj1EOR. So that previous and next button that you see is actually arrows on a branch of this project Im working on, they are anchor tags. Then.. you cant see this in the picture but I am manually putting the month between the `<a>` tags

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Could you solve this? Is your code based on this demo then? http://mvc.daypilot.org/demo/Month/